# Migrating a nested polymorphic record to a new relationship using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, models, nested-attributes

This is a tough one.  I have the following models:

```
 class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :accountable, :polymorphic => true

 class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :account, as: :accountable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :account, :allow_destroy => true

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :account, as: :accountable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :account, :allow_destroy => true
```

Now, lets say that someone already has an account as a `User` but they go to register as a `Professional.`  We want to essentially say "if this person trying to register already has a user account then professional record and migrate their user account over to be associated with the professional account."

So in spec terms:

```
describe "A person with an existing user account for their email address", focus: true do
  before(:each) do
    @user = create(:user, account_attributes: {email: 'testdesigner@test.com', password: 'testing', password_confirmation: 'testing'})
  end

  it "can still sign up as a professional with the same email address" do
    # need to transfer the user account to the professional and delete it
    pro = Professional.new(first_name: 'Test', last_name: 'Designer', company_name: 'A Design Firm', account_attributes: {email: 'testdesigner@test.com', password: 'testing', password_confirmation: 'testing'})

    pro.save.should be_true

    account = Account.find_by_email(@user.email)
    account.accountable_type.should eql 'Professional'

    pro.account.should eql account
  end
end
```

but no matter what we try (before after hooks, trying to modify the nested attributes in the person model, update_only and reject_if on the accepts_nested_attributes_for) we cant seem to get this to work in the model)

What we really need to do is bypass the accepts_nested_attributes_for record creation entirely if a current account for that person of type User exists, but if we put in a reject_if then it stops the creation of the parent record (i.e. Professional) entirely.

Any ideas how we can make this happen

Comment: One comment - we know we can do this all in the controller before calling create, but since this is data driven we would like to handle it entirely in the models.

Answer (score -1):

Updated the solution for you to use your existing model structure:

```
class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :assign_existing_account_if_exists

  has_one  :account, as: :accountable, dependent: :destroy
  delegate :email, to: :account, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account, :allow_destroy => true

  private

  def assign_existing_account_if_exists
    account_to_assign = Account.find_by_email(self.account_email)
    self.account = account_to_assign if account_to_assign.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: No STI would not work in this case as the Professional and User model attributes are completely different.  Besides, that would not help to answer the question unless you are implying that the User model usurp the account model, which we are not looking to do.